# lemma about absolutely continuous function

Tags: functional-analysis, functions

i found this Lemma about absolutely continuous function

> Let $u [0,T] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^d $ an absolutely continous function , then
>   \begin{equation}
> \int_0^T <\dot{u}(t), u(t) > dt = \frac{1}{2} [ \| u(T) \| ^2 - \| u(0) \| ^2] .
> \end{equation}

the lemma was without proof so i wrote the following one, and i hope you correct it for me

\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
<\dot{u}(t), u(t) > &= < \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{u(t+h) - u(t)}{h}, u(t) >\\
&=\lim_{h \to 0}\frac{1}{h} [ <u(t+h) , u(t) > - <u(t), u(t) > ] \\
& \text{since}\;  u(t+h) = u(t) + h\dot{u}(t) + h \frac{e(h)}{h} \; , \,\frac{e(h)}{h} \to 0\;  when \; h \to 0 \\
&= \lim_{h \to 0}\frac{1}{h} [ <u(t+h) , u(t+h) > -<u(t+h), h \dot{u}(t) +h \frac{e(h)}{h}> -  <u(t), u(t) > ]\\
&=\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{1}{h}[\|u(t+h)\|^2 - \|u(t)\|^2 ] -\lim_{h \to 0} <u(t+h),  \dot{u}(t) + \frac{e(h)}{h}>\\
&= \frac{d}{dt} \|u(t) \|^2 - <u(t), \dot{u}(t) > \\
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
then  $2<\dot{u}(t) , u(t) > = \frac{d}{dt} (\|u(t) \| ^2)$

and by integrating we got the result.

thank you so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Your derivation is correct (assuming: 1. $u$ is differntiable; 2. $\|u\|^2$ is absolutely continuous). Another approach is to reduce to one-dimension. Here are the details.

Without loss of generality, assume $u(0)=0$.

Let $e$ be any unit vector. Then $u\cdot e$ is absolutely continuous to ${\mathbb R}$. Now $(u\cdot e)$ and $(u\cdot e)^2$ is also absolutely continuous on ${\mathbb R}$ (reason: $(b^2-a^2) \le 2\max\{|a|,|b|\}(|b|-|a|)$, and recall that $u\cdot e$ is bounded), and $\frac{d}{dt} (u\cdot e)^2=2(u\cdot e) (u'\cdot e)$.  Therefore,

$$ (*) \quad (u(T)\cdot e)^2 =\int_0^T 2(u'\cdot e)(u\cdot e) dt. $$

Since for any two vectors in ${\bf a},{\bf b} \in {\mathbb R}^d$  $({\bf a},{\bf b}) = \sum_{j=1}^n ({\bf a},e_j)({\bf b},e_j)$, where $\{e_1,\dots,e_n\}$ is any orthonormal basis, it follows that

1. $$\|u(T)\|^2 =(u(T),u(T)) =  \sum_{j=1}^d (u(T),e_j)^2.$$
2. $$(u'(t),u(t)) = \sum_{j=1}^d (u'(t),e_j) (u(t),e_j).$$

Plugging these identities into $(*)$ gives the result.